# Fill down based on contents of adjacent cell or other sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in Column A, from A5 to A50 but the end point is subject to change.

I want to select B5 to Y5 and fill down to the end of column A (in this case to row 50, but this will change every time).

The amount of rows depends on another sheet.

As an alternative to my question above, is there is a way to go to the other sheet, and count the rows in column A, from A4 down and then fill down in my other sheet that amount?

**Summary**
- I have one sheet with the data, starting at A4 and going down for an amount that will be changing.
 - I would like to fill down on another sheet the number of rows there are in the first sheet.

**Edit**

The code I tried with macro recorder is listed below. Right now it just selects the area that I need for this case. The A5:Y5 Select will always be the same but the amount of rows to fill down will be variable. I was hoping there is a way to count A5:A1000 of another sheet and then just fill down that number of rows.

```
Sub Macro1()
Macro1 Macro
    Sheets("Stress Test").Select
    Range("A5:Y5").Select
    Range("A5:Y50").Select
    Selection.FillDown
End Sub
```

Comment: You should post the code that you've tried otherwise you may not get help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to receive the best possible help from the site.

Answer (score 0):

Put the name of the other sheet into this and adjust as needed:

```
lastRow = Sheets("name of the other sheet").Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], _
 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Range("A5:Y" & lastRow).Select
```